# Rails: Create a new Active Record Object every week

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a week model. I would like to automatically create a new week object at the beginning of each week (e.g. Sunday midnight) according to the specific time zone a user is in. A user has many weeks. How do you go about this in a rails application?

Comment: Do you want to do this on an activity done by the user weekly or you would like to create the entry anyway?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but I would like to create the week no matter what. It should not rely on an action by the user. Essentially, I am creating a task manager and would like to generate a new week, every week in which the user can add tasks to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a gem to help you with this. Check this out:

Revised railcast
http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby-revised

https://github.com/javan/whenever

With this gem you can write something like this:

```
every :saturday, at: "4:38am" do
...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `clockwork` gem for this

https://github.com/adamwiggins/clockwork

Using clockwork you can do the following

```
require 'clockwork'
include Clockwork

handler do |job|
  puts "Running #{job}"
end

every(10.seconds, 'frequent.job')
every(3.minutes, 'less.frequent.job')
every(1.hour, 'hourly.job')

every(1.day, 'midnight.job', :at => '00:00')

#in your case
every(1.week, 'create_week.job', :at => '00:00')
```